# Question on the MVP within GWT. (General Overview)

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications, mvp

Could any of you guys give a good explanation of the MVP pattern with regards to use in a GWT application. any example i have viewed, i found it hard to understand the concept of implementing the pattern.

Questions such as what is it?
what does it achieve,
how is it implemented
and how can it be extended for future modifications?

Comment: Look at this: http://www.ongwt.com/post/2009/08/16/GWT-MVP-(Model-View-Presenter)-Link-directory

Comment: What, no direct link to Ray Ryan's talk on architecting GWT apps that started this whole MVP + GWT love? It's a must-watch. http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html

Comment: I give some explanation to my implementation of the pattern in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832779/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-use-the-observer-pattern-in-mvp-using-gwt/2832919#2832919 Maybe that could be of some help?

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html and http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html

Comment: Yup, all the info you need is there.

Answer (score 2):

The primary goal of the MVP pattern is to separate the controlling of your UI from the implementation of your UI. You can think of these two concerns as a splitting of the traditional "view" in MVC.

One of the key benefits is that your presenters should be completely testable without any reference to UI widgets, etc. For GWT, this is particularly valuable since tests that use GWTTestCase can be particularly slow.

Comment: i was wondering if i could get a break down , in some ones point of view on each section of the MVP, including sample code as most examples , can be very meaningless,at least if we discuss it here, we can ensure the of the correct implmentation

Comment: The links already posted by others provide some pretty solid grounding, IMHO.