# Any tutorials on the official GWT MVP framework?

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

Has anyone found/written any tutorials on the official GWT MVP framework that's found in the GWT 2.1 RC?

Comment: I give some explanation to my implementation of the pattern in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832779/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-use-the-observer-pattern-in-mvp-using-gwt/2832919#2832919 Maybe that could be of some help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google have updated their large scale web application development series with a [sample application](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=Tutorial-hellomvp-2.1.zip) and [extensive documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) that demonstrates their new MVP support in GWT 2.1 (Model/Activity/Views as they call it now)

Answer (score 3):

Not a tutorial but I wrote one sample that one can use as a skeleton. 
http://code.google.com/p/hello-goodbye-mvp/

Answer (score 2):

A promising series of tutorials on GWT 2.1 MVP started with this article:

http://www.over-look.com/site/index.php/documentation/techblog/item/gwt-2-1-tutorial-1-mvp-the-model

Comment: Wow. That looks a bit convoluted in regards to the model. I hope the Presenter isn't like that or else I'll just use GWTP.

Answer (score 1):

This blog shows how to use Activities and Places and provides similiraties with Gmail (what is a place and what is an activity). I suggest you to read the different post and the questions and answers from the comments because they are quite enlightening.

[web](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html).  Part 2 of that article has a link to a sample project download.

Also, watch this [presentation](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) by Ray Ryan.  I highly recommend to download a PDF file with slides, because, for whatever reason, the cameraman decided to focus on Ray, instead of code.

Comment: I've watched both the presentation and have read the articles. The presentation is probably the clearest in documentation in regards to the new MVP framework, whereas the articles you referenced aren't quite like the new MVP framework.

In fact, the new MVP framework uses new terminology. Instead of "Presenter", they are called "Activities." 

I think part of the problem is that Ray Ryan himself admitted that this framework isn't even finished yet.

Comment: @anonymous. Care to explain downwote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but JP is asking about the new MVP framework coming in GWT 2.1. Your links aren't about that.

Answer (score 0):

Google has tutorial on **Official GWT MVP Framework**, visit below link to start/view that tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture

//Fahim Aslam | Software Engineer