# guava EventBus : would/should this be GWT-compatible?

Tags: java, gwt, reflection, annotations, guava

since version 10 guava offers [com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus](http://code.google.com/searchframe#UKMs0lhE9bg/trunk/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.java&q=EventBus%20package%3ahttp://guava-libraries%5C.googlecode%5C.com) - a generic pub-sub facility. It is not marked as GWT-compatible in the source. I wonder whether it's possible to plug some custom code pre-processing into gwt compiler to map this (partially annotation/reflection-based) API into javascript.

AFAIK there're some other custom extensions added into GWT java-to-js compiler, like [com.google.gwt.i18n.client.ConstantsWithLookup](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nConstants#ConstantsWithLookup) and quite likely some others. I'd seen some experimental compiler extensions to add partial support for reflection/annotations, but not sure they're required in case we handle a specific set of annotations and simple class->methods->annotation listing is required (not a complete reflection API).

Maybe someone knows whether GWT-enabling this component is planned by guava dev team?

Thanks,
Anton

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for guava-discuss than for StackOverflow, but Guava team member here: no, we're not planning on it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it might be a good idea to re-post your statement as an answer so that I close the question?

Comment: There is this: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html

Comment: @Ray yup, I know about that one. A bit of disclosure: we'd evaluated GWT's EventBus and came to conclusion that our couple of extra features mandate implementing an EventBus from scratch. Now I read the samples of guava's EventBus and it's so interesting that I'd try to recode our version against it, if it's possible to port guava's EventBus to GWT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably more appropriate for guava-discuss than for StackOverflow, but Guava team member here: no, we're not planning on it.

Answer (score -1):

simply already working (GWT server+client compatible) with this one: **http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html**

and here (Tutorial): **http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html#events**

(answered also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28082823/1915920)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Mike Kobit: the second link is the answer and points to the provided GWT implementation/functionality itself! Please give me a +1 instead of -1 (if you did not understand the answer itself at the start) because its the best answer you could get for such questions if the functionality is provided where it should be! Thanks anyways

Comment: I didn't downvote, but see [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for information about providing context for links.

Comment: @Mike Kobit: ok, thanks. So I moved the first link on my hasty answer to the bottom which should be fine I guess. (and had a quick look at your link)